# Camera for free

Tags: camera-recommendation

I am 21 years old, and I am in love with capturing pictures, it is my dream to do this all the time (mostly nature and children). I don't have camera, I do it with my phone all the time :( And also I don't have money to buy some nice camera that would take decent pictures. So is there anyone out here who is having like extra camera that is old and usable to give it to me? Or at least you could give me some advice about cheap cameras out there which I could buy? 
Thank you a lot

Comment: What country and city are you in?

Answer (score 8):

> I don't have camera, I do it with my phone all the time :(

There it is: a free camera. You already own your phone, continuing to use it is free. What's the matter using that?

> Or at least you could give me some advice about cheap cameras out there which I could buy?

Just buy a used camera. There's a huge market.
Mostly everybody has a limited budget (even those buying gear for several thousand $). If you want to do this for a living, you need a better business plan than to beg others to give you gear for free. Begging clients to buy your pictures will not work out too well.

Speaking of business: **get a job**. Ask photographers in your area if you can work as an assistant. This will allow you to

- earn money to buy your own private gear
- learn a lot about the business side of things
- get more experience how to work with clients
- do what you want to do (or at least something similar) without having to own the gear yourself

From this you can learn and grow. You might eventually start a business of your own. Or you might continue working with the other photographer with each of you specialising in different genres, sharing gear and costs.

My personal opinion: asking to get gear for free is a cheap excuse. If you really wanted this, you'd be doing it. You mention that you own a phone. What did that cost? What does the contract of the network cost you every month? I'm not saying this is easy, but it ain't as impossible as you make it look like either.

Answer (score 3):

As null pointed, you HAVE a camera.

Joining someone as an assistant is a great idea as well.

In addition, check out freecycle.org for a local group, craigslist and other places to see if someone is willing to part with a camera. Usually, these will not be top of the line and will have functional issues in many situations, but you still may find a usable camera.